# How to improve eloquent nested foreach performance

Tags: php, laravel

How can I improve the performance of a query with the following characteristics (this is a simulation to exemplify):

```
public function getData() 
{
    $itens = Item::orderBy('id_item', 'DESC')->get();

    foreach($itens as $item){
        $item->games = $item->games()->get();

        foreach( $item->games as $player){
            $item->players = $player->players()->get();
        }
    }
    
    return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'itens'=>$itens]);
}
```

In my real case, the foreach returns a lot of data with performance problems;

> The Waiting (TTFB), that is, the time the browser is waiting for the
> first byte of a response, takes almost 27s

Comment: set relationhips and use eagerloading

Comment: I don't know if I got it right: do you suggest replacing foreach with relashionships? How?

Comment: is this the structure of your db `items`->`games`->`players` ?

Comment: Thanks. medilies. Although my real case is more complicated, the structure will be identical to this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Item extends Model{
  // ...

  public function games(){
    return this->hasMany(Game::class);
  }

  public function players(){
    return this->hasManyThrough(Player::class ,Game::class);
  }
}
```

```php
public function getData() 
{
    $itens = Item::orderBy('id_item', 'DESC')->with('games','players')->get();
    
    return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'itens'=>$itens]);
}
```

That will result in 3 queries and the output will be like:

```
[
  // item 0 ...
  [
    // item data
    [
      // games
    ],
    [
      // players
    ]
  ],

  // other items
]
```

Comment: Thanks kingan and medilies. I will try to implement these solutions in my case

Comment: @josei you are welcome. You should avoid that kind of looping and doing queries, that would not allo your application to scale. If I was in your place I may consider using **joins**

Comment: do you suggest that in these cases just use SQL joins instead of eloquent?

Comment: @josei It highly depends on many factors. Note that a JOIN will result in one query while each relationship call will result in an extra query (That doesn't always mean a performance issue). But the data structure returned by the eager loading is definitely better. (you can use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar to see more details about your queries)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
public function getData() 
{
    $items = Item::with('games.players')->orderBy('id_item', 'DESC')->get();
    
    return response()->json(['success'=>true, 'items'=>$items]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code based solutions:

- Looping on array is around 2 times cheaper than looping on List.
- A 'for' loop is much faster than 'foreach'

a other solutio is:

- Filtering unnecessary parts for running the loop

Comment: He has a bigger issue within his loops, and it isn't the cost of repeated computation but it is the amount of queries that his code will generate.